# Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_row_css_class()

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

I'm wonder what happened to my website.  When I go to it now I get this error on the page.  Would anyone be able to help me with the code in line 50?

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_row_css_class() in /home4/mallori1/public_html/wp-content/themes/hazel/vc_templates/vc_row.php on line 50

Below is line 50 when I follow the pathway:

```
$css_class = apply_filters( VC_SHORTCODE_CUSTOM_CSS_FILTER_TAG, 'vc_row wpb_row section '. ( $this->settings('base')==='vc_row_inner' ? 'vc_inner ' : '' ) . get_row_css_class() . $el_class . vc_shortcode_custom_css_class( $css, ' ' ), $this->settings['base'], $atts );
```

Comment: delete this file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just googled and found potential solution, see Robert Hall's comment at:

https://www.8theme.com/topic/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-get_row_css_class/

He suggests deleting the woopress/vc_templates/vc_row.php. In your case if you ftp it will be the vc_row.php located below your public_html folder at:

wp-content/themes/hazel/vc_templates/vc_row.php

**Warning** I would suggest keeping a local copy of vc_row.php just in case, so you can replace it. Also perhaps rename to start with rather than delete. I can't guarantee this will help, but looks promising.

Also note the comments below that point out that this solution will work with some templates, but with others like Newsmag it may result in the loss of content. Therefore, please keep back up of vc_row.php and test before going to production.

Comment: @MMA did it work? It would be helpful for other SO members to know. If it didn't help then I will delete my answer so as not to send people in the wrong direction. If it did help please mark as accepted using the tick so people know it may help in their case. Thanks.

Comment: I dont know what happens with this theme but with another theme if you remove vc_row.php maybe you will lose content

Comment: Im downvoting this answer because removing this file will cause some more issues on some templates (like Newsmag)

Comment: @MidouCloud, thanks for pointing out the limitations of the solution. I have adjusted my answer to reflect your observations. I have left the answer as for some it will help and if they follow the guidance they can try and revert back to original situation if comments lost.

Comment: The last update of Visual Composer fix this kind of error.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens with many Wordpress Themes, so i suggest to add this function to your functions.php on your theme.

```
function get_row_css_class() {
$custom = vc_settings()->get( 'row_css_class' );

return ! empty( $custom ) ? $custom : 'vc_row-fluid';}
```

This is used on many Wordpress Themes and if you remove the call to this function on your /vc_templates/vc_row.php maybe you will lose some of your css classes on your site.